# Shortest time between multiple locations using public transport?

Tags: public-transport, routes

I'm wondering if anyone has/knows of a tool that can find the shortest time to travel between multiple locations on a map using public transport? Google maps only allows for A->B journeys with no additional stops using public transport. A solution in the form of python code is perfectly valid if it has to come to that.
Thanks!

EDIT: This would be for a city sized area in the UK

---

Comment: While a very handy planner for journeys in the UK, it does not have a map, sorry, I thought it might: https://www.traveline.info/

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? e.g. do you just need to pass by the intermediate location? do you need to stop there? how long do you intend to stop for? This is also probably why the journey planners often cannot handle this type of itineraries.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for the "traveling salesman" problem?

Comment: @littleadv: it's even a little more complicated that the TSP, because you have to choreograph your trips to avoid spending all day waiting at bus stops.

Comment: @xngtng I'd be looking to stop at locations for a set length of time before continuing on with the journey. I basically want to chain together Google maps' journey planner by setting different destinations at different times and combining them together. I know it can be done manually when trying each route but it is slow and tedious.